# how to set vscode intellisense to work with nvm

Tags: node.js, intellisense, visual-studio-code, nvm

I'm havibg trouble setting up vscode to work with `nvm`. I've installed node 13.12.0 by running `nvm install node` it's installed in my `home` folder under `/home/$USER/.nvm/versions/node/v13.12.0`.

I don't seem to have entirety of `js` intellisense in vscode. It seems to pick node modules installed with `yarn`, but not global modules like `fs` or `readline`. I was able to set some workarounds for debugging by setting `runTimeExecutable` in `launch.json`.

I've set some setting to use `nvm` path, but no matter what I do I can't get intellisense to work properly.

```
"eslint.nodePath": "/home/$USER/.nvm/versions/node/v13.12.0/bin/node",
"eslint.packageManager": "yarn",
"prettier.packageManager": "yarn",
"npm.packageManager": "yarn",
"typescript.npm": "/home/$USER/.nvm/versions/node/v13.12.0/bin/npm",
"eslint.runtime": "/home/$USER/.nvm/versions/node/v13.12.0/bin/node",
"code-runner.runInTerminal": true
```

This seems to be a common issue with `nvm`, any suggestions on how to remedy this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging around came across the [post](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205964744/comments/205060164) on jebrains support site.

Acording to the post, NVM patches environment variables on terminal startup only. If the IDE is launched from Terminal, it inherits Terminal environment (including modified `PATH` environment variable, added `NVM_DIR`, `env`, `var`, etc). In that case, there are normally no problems with using node/npm, because IDE sees the correct PATH value.

As a work arround I've modief the launch commands in menu entry to `zsh -c "/usr/bin/code-oss --no-sandbox --unity-launch %F"`, unfortunately it doesn't seem to be saved. Do I need to make a custom `.desktop` file?

Also what are the switches `--no-sandbox --unity-launch %F`? I assume the `--no-sandbox` is for isolation, the other one I'm not sure.